# Get element from child directive in parent one

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How I can get element with class `.second` from `second` directive in `link` function of `first` directive?

http://plnkr.co/edit/PiCyZzgvdwAuOyNKOi9E?p=preview

P.S it works with `template` in `link` functions, but I need `templateUrl`.

Comment: You can, but why do you need it? You realize that this is bad practice?

Comment: I don't know angular.js (reading questions here to learn it), but I know other MVVM implementations in the browser, and accessing an element like this creates tight coupling between your view and presentation or business logic. You should probably consider communicating that value through two-way binding via the view model or a service

Comment: it's very simplified variant of my task and there I have templateUrl and I need to get element like this.

Comment: dfsq, can you explain please, why it's a bad practice doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using templateURL, the HTML need to be "downloaded" and then it is an asynchronous event which takes some time.

You could work around that with a timeout, but that wouldn't be clean as you don't know how long to wait.

One option, **if `<second>` is supposed to always be inside `<first>`**, is to run a callback from it once it is ready, from its own link function:

```
{
  restrict: "E",
  templateUrl:'second.html',
  link: function(scope) {
    scope.onSecondReady();
  }
}
```

Check this plunkr for the full code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NLdWaL8zRYkroGC7ZkYL?p=preview

Now if `<second>` is supposed to be re-usable in different context, and not always within the first one, then you need to use events. Once second is ready, you use `scope.$emit('second-is-ready')` and from the first one you listen to it `scope.$on('second-is-ready')`